# Iterating through object array and changing values of multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a function where I am sending in an object, `wholesaler`. There is an array of objects, `wholesalers` which contains multiple `wholesaler` objects.

[image]

I need the order number of the wholesaler that just came in to be increased by 1 and then find the wholesaler object that has a current ORDER of the new value and subtract 1.

```
    $scope.wholesalers = [];
    $scope.downWholesaler = function (wholesaler) {
        if (wholesaler.id > 0) {
            var orderNumber = wholesaler.ORDER;
            var orderBelowNumber = orderNumber + 1;
            angular.forEach($scope.wholesalers, function (myWholesaler) {
                if (myWholesaler.ORDER === orderNumber) {
                    // raise current order +1
                    var add = orderNumber + 1
                    myWholesaler.ORDER = add;
                }
                //setting it
                if (myWholesaler.ORDER === orderBelowNumber) {
                    //lower one with order below number -1
                    var subtract = orderNumber - 1;
                    myWholesaler.ORDER = subtract;
                }
            });
            console.log($scope.wholesalers);
        }
    };
```

Above I am working on doing this. I go through `$scope.wholesalers` and increase the current objects ORDER number and then reduce the one next to it (ORDER +1) down one.

But the ORDER is going down and the next object is not changing at all. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

edit: didn't have lastest code

Comment: Why do you loop over the array looking for an entry with an order number equal to the order that just came in? Wouldn't that be *the order that just came in?* And why are you modifying the order numbers anyway?

Comment: @Draco18s I think I see what you are saying. my if statement is using the wrong object? I have to modify order numbers here for a UI.

Comment: `var orderNumber = wholesaler.ORDER;` and `if (myWholesaler.ORDER === orderNumber) { ... }` Is there ever going to be *two* orders with the same order number? If not, then why not just directly modify the order being processed?

Comment: @Draco18s Good point. But I still need to modify 1 other wholesaler.order as well.

Comment: Start debugging: `alert(myWholesaler.ORDER + " === " + orderBelowNumber);`  Of course, as I was typing this comment it looks like you sovled your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix:

```
    $scope.downWholesaler = function (wholesaler) {
        if (wholesaler.id > 0) {
            var add = parseInt(wholesaler.ORDER) + 1

            angular.forEach($scope.wholesalers, function (myWholesaler) {
                if (myWholesaler.ORDER == add) {
                    myWholesaler.ORDER = parseInt(myWholesaler.ORDER) - 1;
                }
            });

            wholesaler.ORDER = add;

            console.log($scope.wholesalers);
        }
    };
```